# Data gets corrupted when printing structure member variables in C and also to determine the efficiency of JSON parser

Tags: c, parsing, structure, padding

When i uncomment the below 3 printf statements the data in the keytype variables get corrupted. The issue is related to structure padding or ordering the elements but i am not able to understand.
Also i have another ask that is to determine the efficiency of code.

I have attached the source code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
//The size of array includes the null character occupancy also.
    char key1value[50];
    char key2value[20];
    char key3value[10];
}JSON_DATA;

typedef struct
{
    char keytype[5];
    JSON_DATA jd;

}REQUEST;

int getJsonKeyValue(char *requestBuffer,char *key,char *keyValue)
{
    int len = 0;
    int pos = 0;
    int posFirst = 0;
    int posSecond = 0;
    char keyName[100] = "";
    char *ch;

    len = strlen(requestBuffer);
    if(len<=0)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    memset(keyName,0,sizeof(keyName));
    strcpy(keyName,"\"");
    strcat(keyName,key);
    strcat(keyName,"\"");

    for(pos = 0;pos<=len;pos++)
    {
        if(!memcmp(keyName,requestBuffer+pos,strlen(keyName)))
        {
            posFirst = pos + strlen(keyName)+1;//Added plus 1 for colon character
            break;
        }

    }

    
    //Find the second double quote position for the key value
    ch = strchr(requestBuffer+posFirst+1,'\"');
    posSecond = (int)(ch - requestBuffer);
    /*
        adding plus 1 in source arg to exclude the 
        starting double quote character and
        subtracted 1 in the length arg to exclude
        the ending double quote charcater
    */
    strncpy(keyValue,requestBuffer+posFirst+1,posSecond-posFirst-1);
    printf("length of keyValue = %d\n",strlen(keyValue));

    
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char request[] = "{\"keytype\":\"T_MSG\",\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\",\"key3\":\"value3\"}";

    REQUEST req;
    printf("size of JSON_DATA structure = %d\n",sizeof(req));
    memset(&req,0,sizeof(req));

    getJsonKeyValue(request,"keytype",req.keytype);
    getJsonKeyValue(request,"key1",req.jd.key1value);
    getJsonKeyValue(request,"key2",req.jd.key2value);
    getJsonKeyValue(request,"key3",req.jd.key3value);

    printf("Inside main\n");
    printf("keytype = |%s|\n",req.keytype);
    printf("key1value = |%s|\n",req.jd.key1value);
    printf("key2value = |%s|\n",req.jd.key2value);
    printf("key3value = |%s|\n",req.jd.key3value);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
length of keyValue = 5
length of keyValue = 6
length of keyValue = 6
length of keyValue = 6
Inside main
keytype = |T_MSGvalue1|
key1value = |value1|
key2value = |value2|
key3value = |value3|
```

The data in keytype should have been |T_MSG| but it gets corrupted.

2. If i change the order of structure member below

```
typedef struct
{
        JSON_DATA jd;
        char keytype[5];


}REQUEST;
```

The output is as below

Output

```
Inside main
keytype = |T_MSG{"keytype":"T_MSG","key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}|
key1value = |value1|
key2value = |value2|
key3value = |value3|
```

Comment: You don't need to `memset()` before `strcpy()`.

Answer (score 0):

`strncpy()` doesn't add a null terminator at the end of the copy. So when you copy into `keyValue` you're creating strings without a terminator.

So after the `strncpy()` you need to do:

```
keyValue[posSecond-posFirst] = '\0';
```

Also, since you know there's no null terminator in the part of the source string that you're copying from, you can use `memcpy()` instead of `strncpy()`.

The reason your final output is wrong is because `char keytype[5];` doesn't have room for the null terminator after `T_MSG`. The size of that array has to be at least 1 more than the largest possible `keyType` value. Or you could make it a pointer to an array that's allocated dynamically with `malloc()`, they it should handle any size (you can do the same with the values in the `JSON_DATA` struct).

Comment: I have added the strlen function in the getJsonKeyValue and it is printing correct length for msg_type but have a problem is when it prints the structure variables.

```
printf("length of keyValue = %d\n",strlen(keyValue));

```

Comment: `char keytype[5];` isn't big enough, it doesn't have room for the null terminator after `T_MSG`

Comment: To All, i have posted the complete source code at https://applicationsincprogramming.blogspot.com/2020/11/simple-json-parser-in-c-without.html
Appreciate all.